# Need assistance with wp_user_query not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need some help getting a wp_user_query to work; been struggling and trying lots of stuff but cannot get it to work proper way.

here is my code:

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'role'     => 'personal-injury-lawyer',
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'lawyer_numeric_rank',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        array(
            'key'     => 'lawyer_location',
            'value'   => 'London',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    )
);

$london_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);  

if ( ! empty($london_user_query->results)) {
    foreach ( $london_user_query->results as $user ) {
```

I know the foreach loop is not closed; just trying shorten this...

I am trying to do three things on this query:

1. Show roles of `personal-injury-lawyer`
2. Show where `meta_key` field of `lawyer_location` = London
3. Order by `meta_value` where `meta_key` = `lawyer_numeric_rank` in ASC order

I have tried this a number of ways but cannot get this to work with both filtering on London location and also ordering by the rank...

The code right now does filter on location; but the orderby part is not working; if i remove the location filter from this; then the orderby does work...

I hope someone can help with this.

Comment: The sub-array you would use to compare `lawyer_location` against `London` does not have a key.

Comment: thanks for commenting phaberest but that is the first item in my subarray; 'key'     => 'lawyer_location',

Comment: not saying you are wrong but that is what I am seeing .. thanks

Comment: Read the [Class Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query), that array is not interpreted correctly.

Comment: I actually started with that page; but could not get it all to work using the directions on there; so I have been searching around trying different things with no luck; it seems like it is interpreting that array as it does filter by location...but the orderby does not work...I dont know if that helps clarify this or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were forming the meta query argument incorrectly. The below code should help you with quite a few more meta queries as well.

```
$args = array(
    'role'=> 'personal-injury-lawyer', //assuming you have created a role that corresponds..
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'lawyer_numeric_rank',  
    'meta_query' => array(
      // 'relation'=> 'AND', --> if you want more conditions 
        array(
            'key'     => 'lawyer_location',
            'value'   => 'London',
            'compare' => '='
        ),

       /* even more conditions with OR, cumulative effect is match lawyer location AND 1 of the nested arrays


            array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                                'key' => '',
                                'value' => '',
                                'compare' => '=',
                        ),
                        array(
                                'key' => '',
                                'value' => '',
                                'compare' => '=',
                        ),
            ),


       */

    )
);
```